# How to contain UIViewController view between navigation bar and tab bar?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have created a storyboard layout which contains UIViewControllers within UINavigationControllers which all connect back to a UITabBarController. There is a login page which is not connected to anything (just a UIViewController) which segues into the UITabBarController when the app detects user authentication. You can see what this looks like in the following image:

[image: Storyboard Layout]

When I set the translucent property of the Navigation Bar to "false" or "No", the view y origin gets pushed down to the bottom of the Navigation Bar (which is the behavior that I am looking for). However, when I set the translucent property of the Tab Bar to "false" or "No", the Tab Bar DOES become opaque, but the view is not resized to fit between the top and bottom bars. I have unchecked the **Extend Edges** property for both **Under Top Bars** and **Under Bottom Bars** for all UIViewControllers, UINavigationControllers, and the UITabBarController.

[image: Extend Edges]

When I add subviews programmatically (no auto-layout), the UIViewController's view is still the height of the entire screen, and is only pushed down from the top bar, but not pushed up from the bottom bar. While creating this question, this is the result I got on the simulator (subviews are not even starting below the Navigation Bar):

[image: Simulator]

The layout that I'm trying to achieve is to have the view fit between the Navigation Bar and the Tab Bar so that both bars are opaque and no content goes underneath them. Any ideas or suggestions?

EDIT:

After eliminating individual Navigation Controllers and adding a single one before the TabBar Controller, I'm getting weird behavior including navigation items disappearing and one of my subviews still goes under bottom bar.

[image: Simulator]

EDIT 2:

After doing some research, It seems that having navigation controllers inside each tab is a normal view hierarchy. Unfortunately, I still have not figured out how to limit a view controller's view to be between a navigation bar and a tab bar. Any suggestions?

Comment: embed the tab bar in navigation bar, and make the rest of uiview controlelrs just plain.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri, do you mean I should eliminate the TabBarController and add a TabBar to each of the NavigationControllers? Or do you mean I should eliminate all the NavigationControllers and embed the TabBarController (the menu > editor > embed in > NavigationController option is greyed out for the TabBarController)?

Comment: No, I meant to say that you have one navigation controller behind the tab bar controller, and thats it. You dont need a navigaiton controller for the all view controllers connected to tab bar controller.

Comment: I made the change that you suggested and the activity indicator seems to be working properly and placed at the center of the view. However, the navigation items (added programatically) have disappeared and one of my subviews is still going under the bottom bar (and seems to be the full height of the screen). Any ideas? I'll post an image in an edit above.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri what do you think of my update and comment?